# How to send email using nodemailer and gmail?

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer in order to send email to customers.

Here how I configured my transporter :

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
service:'Gmail',
auth: {
    user : "xxxx",
    pass : "xxxx",
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I got "Invalid Login error". I checked on the web and autorized "less security connections" through settings account.

Unfortunately I stuck with the same error...

Could explain me how can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using AWS SES with nodemailer instead of gmail. It is much easier to implement.

Comment: Indeed, AWS SES is far easier to work with for this particular use case.  My personal use case was I needed a server to be able to send emails to some admins every time a user signed up for a given product.  Using Amazon's Simple Email Service was much easier than trying to interface Gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to generate an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for GMail, and use this with Nodemailer.

This will bypass any 2FA dialogs and any 'sign in authorizations' you may get when using your standard password.

See ['using Gmail' in the Nodemailer docs.](https://community.nodemailer.com/using-gmail/)

Comment: Is there a way to force the "from" param ? Cause when I write for exemple "contact@toto.com" gmail replace it with my gmail address...

Comment: You don't want to be 'spoofing' an email address as it will get flagged as spam, if you need this, acquire a domain and use a service such as sendgrid or AWS SES and do it properly

Comment: You can try email forwarding with https://forwardemail.net